# Selecting id of TextArea (despite RichEditableText)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe, mxml

I'm trying to select the id of a textArea when it's focused in

```
<s:TextArea id="textarea1" focusIn="selectId(event)" />

selectId(event){
   event.target.id;
}
```

Problem is `TextArea` is made up of `RichEditableText` so `target` doesn't actually refer to `TextArea`. I've tried `event.target.parent.id` but still not getting there. Anyone knows how to get to the bottom of this?

Comment: Did you try event.currentTarget.id?

Comment: That was it, if you post it I will accept as an answer. Note, it also worked after some testing with `event.target` but had to add 4 `parent` in the middle. Not sure why, I guess that's how many it takes to get from `RichEditableText` to `TextArea`

Comment: @Robusto Why didn't you post it as an answer. @duder `event.target` would be the innermost item that was clicked on - on a button, it can be the text field that displays the label or a skinning component and so on. Don't rely on it here as it needn't always be 4 steps; might vary based on where you clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At @Amargosh's request, I'm posting this as an answer. Try:

```
event.currentTarget.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<s:TextArea id="textarea1" focusIn="selectId(event,this.textarea1)" />

private function selectId(event, item) : void
{
   // Your code to do stuff with item
}
```

In fact, you don't need to send the event argument at all if you aren't going to use it:

```
<s:TextArea id="textarea1" focusIn="selectId(this.textarea1)" />

private function selectId(item) : void
{
   // Your code to do stuff with item
}
```